# Get more information about current user in windows authentication mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

In an Asp.Net MVC 4 windows authentication mode, is it possible to get more information about current user (like name & family)?

Comment: Where do you store windows users: local or in Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the username you can use Active Directory API to get other properties of user. You can use the following code for example:

```
Using System.DirectoryServices;
```

...

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DomainName");
DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(l=" + username + "))";
foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            // Login Name
            Console.WriteLine(GetProperty(result, "cn"));
            // Display Name
            Console.WriteLine(GetProperty(result, "displayName"));
            // Department
            Console.WriteLine(GetProperty(result, "department"));
        }
```

and this can be the GetProperty method:

```
private string GetProperty(SearchResult searchResult, string PropertyName)
    {
        if (searchResult.Properties.Contains(PropertyName))
        {
            return searchResult.Properties[PropertyName][0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

and propertyName can be values like:

- Login Name: "cn"
- First Name: "givenName"
- Middle Initials: "initials"
- Last Name: "sn"
- Address: "homePostalAddress"
- ...